# Не отображается echo из-за ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Данные добавляются в БД. Echo ничего не выводит

```
    <script>
            function getdetails(){
              var name = $('#name').val();
              var text = $('#text').val();
              var id = $('#id').val();
              var id_room = $('#id_room').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "add_comment.php",
                    data: {name:name, text:text,id:id,id_room:id_room}
                }).done(function( result )
                    {
                         $("#msg").html( " " +id + " " +id_room+ " " + name+ " " + text );
                    });
            }
            </script>
 <div id="msg"></div>
<?

require_once('connect.php');

    $name= $_POST['name'];   
    $id_room= $_POST['id_room'];  
    $id= $_POST['id'];      
    $review_text= $_POST['text'];   

$insert="INSERT INTO room_review (id_room,id_user,name,text_review) values ('$id_room','$id','$name','$review_text')";
$query="SELECT * from room_review where id_review=(SELECT MAX(id_review) FROM room_review)and id_room='$id_room'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$insert);
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$query);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

echo $row['name'];
echo $row['text_review'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное нужно не **[mysqli_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)**, а **[mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)**, либо писать `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`. Потому что, возможно, возвращается не ассоциативный массив, а нумерованный `$row[0], $row[1]...$row[N]`, не смотря на дефолтное значение функции `MYSQLI_BOTH`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать в PHP файле строку

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

чтобы клиент понял что он получает JSON данные и что их нужно декодировать. Кроме того возможно стоит обединить выводимые данные в один массив и использовать json_encode, чтобы преобразовать выходные данные в формат JSON.

Answer (score 0):

А как вы это эхо ловите?)))
Вот так надо, я переименовал переменную для большей разжеванности:

```
<script>
function getdetails(){
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var text = $('#text').val();
  var id = $('#id').val();
  var id_room = $('#id_room').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add_comment.php",
    data: {name:name, text:text,id:id,id_room:id_room}
  }).done(function( data_from_server )
  {
    $("#msg").html( " " +id + " " +id_room+ " " + name+ " " + text + data_from_server);
  });
}
</script>
```